# CDI 2.0 (Weld): Can't inject non CDI component

Tags: dependency-injection, wildfly, cdi

In a rest endpoint deployed on Wildfly 20, I need to inject an external non CDI instance of the javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder class. For example:

```
@Path("...")
public class MyResource
{
  ...
  @Inject
  private UriBuilder uriBuilder;
  ...
}
```

Here is the producer:

```
public class UriBuilderProducer
{
  @Produces
  public UriBuilder getUriBuilder()
  {
    return UriBuilder.fromResource(Customer.class);
  }
}
```

The beans.xml file reads as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
   version="2.0" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

However, the deployment fails raising the following exception:

```
15:03:24,837 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myresource.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myresource.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
 Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type UriBuilder with qualifiers @Default
   at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private ...MyResource.uriBuilder
   at ...MyResource.uriBuilder(MyResource.java:0)
```

What did I miss here ?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Kind regards,

Seymour

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I've put the beans.xml in the wrong place. In order to land in the WEB-INF directory of the resulted WAR, one needs to put it in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF and not in src/main/resources/WEB-INF, as one would expect, based on maven COC (Convention Over Configuration) rules.

Having this file in the right place solves the issue, of course. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Kind regards,

Seymour